Web3 frontend can't connect to SC or eth mainnet
My frontend can't connect to SC or mainnet(not sure wich one) since few days ago:
https://presale12.titaneco.tech/
Page shows loading and stuck in it
Please guide me whats wrong and how can i fix it
Appreciate to guide me
